# error: incompatible types: Vb0201 cannot be converted to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My problem is that i want to make a simple JFrame, but i keep getting the same error with this line of code:

JFrame frame = new Vb0201();

The error that i get is:

> error: incompatible types: Vb0201 cannot be converted to JFrame

The full sourcecode is:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Vb0201 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new Vb0201();
        frame.setSize( 400, 200 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setTitle( "Eerste applicatie" );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this should work? `Vb0201` does not extend `JFrame`.

Comment: If you want a JFrame then create a new JFrame. `Vb0201 does not extend JFrame.` - and it shouldn't.

Comment: I just copy and paste it from a book that i try to follow. I just got started. And Vb0201 is the name of the class.

Comment: ... and you may be copying incorrectly. In the future, search on your error message, as this sort of thing has been asked many times before.

Comment: It may be the name of the class but that doesn't mean anything. When you execute the class the JVM just executes the main() method of the class. I suggest you start with the `FrameDemo.java` code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a better structured example of making a basic JFrame.

Comment: camickr thanx for the link. I found the problem and instead of this code:

Comment: Instead of this code:

Comment: JFrame frame = new Vb0201();           I wrote this code and it worked: JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vb0201");

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish for your class to extend JFrame then you simply need to change the line of code to this.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

This is because you are trying to create a new JFrame (window) type and trying to say that you class Vb0201 is a subtype of this class but is in fact not. For more information on inheritance, search on google.

Hope this helps.